# Bind callback function with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I would like to bind to the element function, which take several arguments. How to do it right?

For example, I have function:

```
function test(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    console.log("arg1:", arg1);
    console.log("arg2:", arg2);
    console.log("arg3:", arg3);
}
```

and I would like to bind this to element with ID `#btn`, but all arguments are in array:

```
var array = ['Hello', ' my', ' world!'];
```

How can I do this? I will try something like this:

```
$("#btn").bind("click", array, test);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: there is a simple solution is by using event data, however you have to change the `test` function prototype.

Comment: Depends. Will `test()` eventually be used to directly handle the click event?

Comment: @Jack ah yes, if it's not, we can use an anonymouse function like `function(e){}` and then access the `e.data` to get the arguments for the `test` function called inside.

Comment: One more question. How can I release `bind` from `#btn` ?

Comment: @Niezbor You mean [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)? Though, `on()` and `off()` are preferable (according to docs).

Comment: @Jack Thanks `unbind` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
var array = ['Hello', ' my', ' world!'];

$("#btn").bind("click", function() {
  test.apply(null, array);
});
```

Or using `$.proxy` method to add the arguments by:

```
$("#btn").bind("click", $.proxy.apply($.proxy, [test, null].concat(array)));
```

Comment: Why first of argument in apply is null?

Comment: @Niezbor First argument decides what is `this` in the function, in op's case, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Niezbor the explanation of xdazz is enough, in fact my explanation was a bit wrong about the `this` keyword, you can still use the `this` keyword in your function ***but*** it will refer to some outer context, such as the `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

Make a closure.

```
$('#btn').bind("click", function() { test('Hello', 'my', 'world'); });
```

or

```
$('#btn').bind("click", function() { test.apply(null, array); });
```

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Sc3r7/)***

You could use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to accomplish that.

```
$("#btn").bind("click", function(){ test.apply({},array)});
```